Error al compilar proyecto Spring para integrar saml2
buen día, me encuentro con este error que ocurre al compilar mi proyecto. Estaba investigando este error pero no pude encontrar una posible solución. Estas son las dependencias que estoy usando y la parte del código de seguridad que implementé , y si tienen sugerencias sobre mi código también me pueden aportar algo para mejorarlo , muchas gracias
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository_2</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-core/4.3.2)</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository_2</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-core/4.3.2)</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // Create a filter to handle generation of SAML Metadata file
        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(
                (RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver)new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository),
                new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

        
        Converter<Assertion, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesExtractor =  assertion -> {

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userRoles
                    = assertion.getAttributeStatements().stream()
                    .map(AttributeStatement::getAttributes)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .filter(attr -> "groups".equalsIgnoreCase(attr.getName()))
                    .map(Attribute::getAttributeValues)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(xml -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + xml.getDOM().getTextContent()))
                    .toList();
            return userRoles;
        };

        Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> authConvertor
                = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter();
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider samlAuthProv = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthProv.setResponseAuthenticationConverter((responseToken) -> {

            Saml2Authentication authentication = authConvertor.convert(responseToken);
            Assertion assertion = responseToken.getResponse().getAssertions().get(0);
            AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = (AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesExtractor.convert(assertion);
            return new Saml2Authentication(principal, authentication.getSaml2Response(), authorities);
        });


        http
                .saml2Login(withDefaults())
                .saml2Logout(withDefaults())
                .authenticationProvider(samlAuthProv) // change : register the new SAML Auth provider
                .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/carsonline", "/buy/**", "/user").hasAnyRole("cars.user","cars.admin")
                                .requestMatchers("/edit/**").hasAnyRole("cars.admin")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        // change : return the SecurityFilterChain
        return http.build();
    }

Aqui les comparto el error que me aparece, si necesitan mas detalle de lo que me aparece antes me pueden comentar y se los coloco:
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RIPEMD160 MessageDigest not available
Intenté colocar esta dependencia y esta parte en mi método principal para poder cubrir ese error de RIPEMD160 MessageDigest not available.
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.64</version>
    </dependency>

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error mencionado anteriormente.
Gracias por su apoyo.
